# Creating an inequality for the numerator significance

Tags: inequality, summation, soft-question, irrational-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

An open mathematical problem is if the Euler-Mascheroni constant is irrational and if so transcendental. There has been some progress in (dis)proving this. It is known that:

> $\gamma\in\mathbb{Q}\implies q\ge10^{244663}$ where $q$ is the denominator of $\gamma$

This is a statement proved by Papanikolaou in his paper [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0054873). So I wonder if an inequality for the numerator, say $p$, is of any significance. What I am asking is, if there is an inequality for the denominator, does having one for the numerator help in proving (ir)rationality? I am asking this question since I found this inequality for the numerator: $$p\ge-\ln\left(\Gamma(10^{244663}+1)\right)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{10^{244663}}{k}-\ln\left(1+\frac{10^{244663}}{k}\right)\right)$$And I wonder if it is of any significance.

Comment: Since we know that the value is (say) between 0.55 and 0.60, doesn't having a bound on the denominator give you a bound on the numerator and vice versa? So won't these bounds have the same (or at least similar) significance?

Comment: An inequality that involves an infinite series is pretty useless, since we already have exact evaluations of $\gamma$ as infinite series.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Calvin. Here are some more thoughts/details:

- If $q \geq B$ for some $B>0$, then $p = \frac{p}{q}\, q \geq \gamma B \approx 0.5572\, B$.
- If $p \geq C$ for some $C>0$, then $q = \frac{q}{p}\, p \geq \gamma^{-1} C \approx 1.732\, C$.
- You should verify that your bound is a positive number, otherwise it is worthless.
- Once this is done, you could check whether your bound is larger than $\gamma B = 0.5772 \cdot 10^{244633}$, only then have you improved the bound found by Papanikolaou.

I have serious doubts that your bound is nonnegative, since
$$
C_{n} = -\ln\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{n}{k}-\ln\left(1+\frac{n}{k}\right)\right) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} -\infty,
$$
where I used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim_%28n%20to%20Infinity%29%20-%20log%28Gamma%28n%2B1%29%29%20%2B%20Sum_%28k%3D1%29%5E%28Infinity%29%20%28n%2Fk%20-%20log%281%2Bn%2Fk%29%29), and your $n = 10^{244633}$ is rather large..

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. Are you sure that as $n$ approaches infinity you get negative infinity? Since I proved that $p=-\ln(\Gamma(q+1))+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac qk-\ln(1+\frac qk)\right)$...

Comment: WA is wrong since $C_n=\gamma\,n$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici what does WA mean?

Comment: I might be mistaken and my confidence in the WolframAlpha result is limited, which is why I added the link so everyone can check for themselves and evaluate its correctness. @ClaudeLeibovici Please elaborate on why $C_n = \gamma n$. $\gamma$ is defined by $\gamma := \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(-\log m + \sum_{k=1}^m \frac1{k}\right)$. Why should it equal $C_n/n$ for each $n$?